# Android Basic TextField alignment in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, alignment, row, android-jetpack-compose

i am having problemas trying to align text in a BasicTextField inside a ROW in Jetpack Compose, the goal is to have the text in total center.

The code is the following:

```
Row(verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {

        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(40.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterVertically),
            value = "Hello",
            onValueChange = {},
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
        )
    }
```

Here is a picture of the result:

[image]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Thanks!

Ariel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found **2 ways to solve this problem**:

**The first** is simpler if `BasicTextField` does not necessarily need to have a height of `40.dp`, and the `Row` component can be responsible for setting a height:

```kotlin
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    BasicTextField(
        value = "Hello",
        onValueChange = {},
        singleLine = true,
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.Center),
    )
}
```

The **second way** is in case your `BasicTextField` really needs to have a height of `40dp`, and this responsibility cannot be assigned to the parent component (`Row`).

The strategy here is to wrap the `BasicTextField` with a box height of `40dp` and then align it to the center of the parent:

```kotlin
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.height(40.dp),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            value = "Hello",
            onValueChange = {},
            textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
        )
    }
}
```

Note that in this second case it was necessary to change the assignment of the `textStyle` parameter of the `BasicTextField`:

```kotlin
Row(...) {
     BasicTextField(
          ...
         textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
     )
}
```

For both cases the visual result will be this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pierre, never thought that changing the row height will center the text in the basictextfield, it appears to be some kind of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Use decorationBox in BasicTextField

```
    BasicTextField(
            value = textState,
            onValueChange = { textState = it },
            decorationBox = { innerTextField ->.  //add this and config yout layout
                Row(
                    modifier = modifier.padding(horizontal = 12.dp),
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {

                        innerTextField()

                }
            },

            )
```